# Grid saveChanges and then filtering changes datasource of the grid in shield ui

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I'm using shield ui for a backoffice I'm creating, but I've found a main issue that I can't seem to solve. I have a grid that has cell editing, window pop up, paging and filtering (both by column and by search). The main issue I'm having is that everytime I edit a register, I save the changes ($("#grid").swidget().saveChanges()), see through console.log that the datasource has changed, if I then filter (by column or by search), the datasource of the grid reverts to its original state. Has anyone found this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem is with the filtering by column that it doesn't refresh the datasource when changes are saved. Is there any way to refresh the datasource that is used for filtering by columns?

Comment: You can use the DataSource's refresh() method - https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/datasource/javascript/api/methods/refresh